# how to get down and up interfaces in linux by using python script

Tags: linux, python-3.x

```
from collections import namedtuple
import re
import subprocess

def get_interfaces(external=False, ip=False):
    pass
```

I am new with Python and was hoping someone could help me:

1. Create an interface.
2. find down and up interfaces in Linux by using a python script.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no standard library in python to manage network interfaces.
The standard tool under Linux is `ip`. You can wrap it using `subprocess`. Like this :

```
import subprocess

for r in subprocess.check_output(["/bin/ip","-o","link"]).split('\n'):
    F = r.split(" ")
    if len(F)>1:
        z=zip(F,F[1:])
        s= filter(lambda (k,v): k=="state", z)
        print z[0][1][:-1], s[0][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [netifaces](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces), I think it can do exactly what you want

```
import netifaces
netifaces.interfaces()
```